# Qualtrics: auto-populate choices' text in multiple-choice questions

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to build a questionnaire in Qualtrics that updates the text of the choices depending on the previous answer. The text that goes into the choices comes from a dataset.

> **Example:**
>
> Dataset:
>
> row1 = [1 ,2, 3]
>
> row2 = [4, 5, 6]
>
> 1. Select between: a) 1;b) 2.
> 2. Select between: a) *changes depending on the answer in 1*; b)3.
>
> Where 2 option a) will be 4 if a) is selected in 1 or 5 if b) is
>   selected in 1.

I have been able to make it work with the Qualtrics tool of display logic, but for this I need to hardcode the values. Does anyone know how to use JavaScript (or other qualtrics tool)to change automatically the text of the choices, i.e. to do what the example shows?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I am new both to Qualtrics and JavaScript, so probably I am missing something.